# Extract month from Date to create unique key using concatenation

Tags: sql, date, string-concatenation

After extracting month from date, I try to concatenate this with another field value to create a unique key usable as a look-up field against another table.

##### Purpose

Create a unique key as a look-up field against another table.

##### SQL:

```
  SET @start_date = '2021-01-01';
  SET @end_date = '2021-12-31';
    
  SELECT
     EXTRACT(month FROM Date) AS Month,
     City,
     PostCode,
     Concat(City, PostCode, Month) AS Unique,  
  FROM table
  WHERE
     (Date >= @start_date AND Date <= @end_date)
```

##### Error message:

> 'Unrecognized name: Month'

Without concatenation, the month generates correctly and yet the variable is unrecognised outside the scope of the extract function.

Comment: You shouldn't name columns using reserved words, in this case `Month`. Other example would be `Unique`

Comment: You can't reference columns defined in the select in that same select. Either nest the select in another select and move the concat there, or repeat the extract expression within the concat.